# React Native app cant install package with Solana dependency

Tags: javascript, react-native

Installing a package that requires [solanaweb3js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/web3.js) in React Native throws an error.

I found that [i am not alone with this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14139) but i could not make the provided solutions work for me.

Error:

```
Error: Unexpected token name «n», expected punc «,» in file node_modules/solana-test-package/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.native.js at 4581:32
    at /Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:279:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:146:24)
    at _next (/Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:168:9)
    at /Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:175:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:164:12
    at minifyCode (/Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:289:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/darjusch/development/solana/wallet-sdk/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:569:40)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Reproducing the error:
Gitclone:
https://github.com/Darjusch/AwesomeProject

OR

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject

npm i solana-test-package
```

I uploaded that npm packge to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/Darjusch/solana-test-package

This is the content of the package:

index.js

```
const { Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');

export function generateKeypair() {
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();
  console.log(`Generated Solana publickey is ${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
  return keypair;
}
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.54.0"
  }
```

Any help appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

That error implies that your JavaScript runtime does not understand `BigInt` literals (eg. `2n`). Newer runtimes like Hermes circa React Native 0.70.0 added support for them.

Follow the updated React Native project initialization instructions at https://solanacookbook.com/integrations/react-native.html#how-to-use-solana-web3-js-in-a-react-native-app